# SQL: Select conversations GROUP BY with last record from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have following problem. I have two tables:

**baz_conversations**

```
con_id, con_users, con_date
```

**baz_con_messages**

```
message_id, message_con_id, message_text, message_author
```

And I want to show all of my conversations - con_users in table baz_conversations MUST CONTAIN myID WITH LAST message from another table of that conversation. I spent too much time of programming this ,,easy,, sql select but it selectin FIRST and NOT LAST message from table baz_con_messages. Thank you for your answers. Here is my code:

```
SELECT m.*, c.* FROM baz_conversations AS c RIGHT JOIN 
                     baz_con_messages AS m ON c.con_id = m.message_con_id
WHERE c.con_users LIKE '%1,%' 
GROUP BY c.con_id 
ORDER BY m.message_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What database are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  You should tag your questions with only the database you are really using.  From the use of `limit`, I would guess MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT m.*, c.*
FROM baz_conversations c JOIN 
     baz_con_messages m
     ON c.con_id = m.message_con_id
WHERE c.con_users LIKE '%1,%' AND
      not exists (select 1
                  from baz_con_messages m2
                  where m2.message_con_id = m.message_con_id and
                        m2.message_id > m.message_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using self join, when you use `GROUP BY` by some common values your results are grouped but not in an ordered way so you cannot expect  using group by that it will give you the latest result for a group so for your case you need the last message id from the conversation group i use another join on baz_conversations as a self join but this time i used the subquery to get the maximum value of message id along with conversation id and joined on two conditions i.e  `USING(message_id , message_con_id )` so the first `baz_con_messages` is joined with new maxima resultset where conversation id is common and also both resultset  matched with message id so the results are returned according to the `MAX(message_id)` only one per conversation group

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  c.* 
FROM
  baz_conversations AS c 
   JOIN baz_con_messages AS m 
   ON c.con_id = m.message_con_id 
   JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(message_id) message_id , message_con_id
    FROM baz_con_messages GROUP BY message_con_id
   ) m2
   USING(message_id , message_con_id )
WHERE c.con_users LIKE '%1,%' 
ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It works but can you tell me more about your answer. I dont understand to your sql query :/ please, if you can describe individual parts of your query, i will be very happy. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user3354689 see my updated answer hope it makes sense